# Swift 3 tableview header custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I had a custom cell being used as a tableview section header. I updated to swift 3 and now it is not showing anymore

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableHeader") as! tableHeader
```

then i put in some constraints and return header

Comment: what was the older version of Swift?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of customCell class.

Comment: im not certain but i think 2.2

Comment: what do you mean by the declaration of the cutomCell Class

Comment: Do you extend your customCell class from UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: Too hard to answer your question, when you are "unsure" about so many stuffs :-( . You need to extend your class from UITableViewHeaderFooterView to ensure it appears in header section.

Comment: I am new to coding and not familiar with all these terms. I set up the code above and created a class as a UItableView Cell. Im not sure what you mean by extend your class from ... can you please explain more

Comment: Create the class as UITableViewHeaderFooterView and it will work.

Comment: Why are you trying to dequeue a cell from the table view to be used as a section header? That is incorrect for so many reasons.

Comment: i found it on here once and used it and worked well until now. If its the wrong way to do it can anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a late answer but for some who did not find the correct answer till. You can use UITableViewSectionHeight. Below is an example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80 // this is your row height
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your custom class should extend from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and it will work.

Comment: if i do that then i can not connect it to the cell i created in storyboard